# Display Daily message after login for each user

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an index page where users can login and they are redirected to dashboard.php, i have started a session

```
require_once("config.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"] == "") {
// not logged in send to login page
redirect("index.php");
```

i want to display a daily message (only once a day for each members)
i have also coded to be visible only from specific ip.

this is what i have, but it doesnt work... it use cookies, i beleave that if i need a daily message for each member i need something else.

```
 <div id="test">
<?php  
    $allow = array("84.232.237.169","188.24.146.118"); //allowed IPs

    if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"], $allow))  {  ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#welcome-modal').modal('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#welcome-modal').modal('hide');
  }, 60000);
});
</script>
<div id="user">
    <div id="welcome-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                    <p>
                    <font size="6">
                    <div align="center"></div>Salut, Nu uita sa te pontezi! <br><br>

                        Click <a href="pontajianuarie.php">AICI</a> pentru a te ponta!

                    </div>
                    </font>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
    <?php
    }
?>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Delete Cookie" onclick="deleteCookie()"/>
<script>
// 'Delete' cookie for testing
function deleteCookie()
{
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
    sessionStorage.returnVisit = "false";
    console.log("sessionStorage set.");
}
else{
    setCookie("return_visit","false",1);
}
}

//W3 Schools setCookie function
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

//W3 Schools getCookie function
function getCookie(c_name)
{
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
  if (c_start == -1)
  {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
  if (c_start == -1)
  {
    c_value = null;
  }
  else
  {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1)
    {
      c_end = c_value.length;
    }
  c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
 }
return c_value;
}

//Check return_visit cookie on page load
function bodyOnload()
{
if(getCookie("return_visit") === 'true' || sessionStorage.returnVisit === "true"){
    //Do something if user has already visited page
            var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.innerHTML = "";
}
else
{
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
        sessionStorage.returnVisit = "true";
        console.log('Session Storage set.');
    }
    else{
        setCookie("return_visit","true",1);
    }
}
}

</script>
```

EDITED:

```
<?php


require_once("config.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"] == "") {
    // not logged in send to login page
    redirect("index.php");
}

?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "highmob";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "highmob_comenzi";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

function show_message($user_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM DAILY_MESSAGES  WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id'] . "";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          if($row['date'] == date('Y-m-d')) {
           if($row['used']==0) {
             echo $row['message'];
            }
          }
       }
    } 
}


function update_message_status($user_id) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE DAILY_MESSAGES SET used=1 WHERE '.$_SESSION['user_id'] . "";
        $conn->query($sql);
    }

?>
```

I have also created the database table nammed DAILY_MESSAGES with 
ID = AI nessage, 
user_id, 
used, 
created_at

I dont get any message or any update into database any ideea?

Answer (score 2):

You could use database, if you are using mysql for example you can create a table DAILY_MESSAGES with this structure:

```
ID: int AI
message: string
user_id: int
used: int
created_at: date
```

Let's say if a user enter to your dashboard you will print the messange and you will update the used field, for example

```
function show_message($user_id) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM daily_messages WHERE user_id='.$user_id;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          if($row['date'] == date('Y-m-d')) {
           if($row['used']==0) {
             echo $row['message'];
            }
          }
       }
    } 
}
```

and for update

```
   function update_message_status($user_id) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE daily_messages SET used=1 WHERE '.$user_id;
        $conn->query($sql)
    }
```

Comment: i dont know why but your script does't add any data to database? :-S

Comment: im getting an error at this line:           if($row['used'] == 0 {

Comment: It’s because a ) is missing.  If($row['used']==0)

Comment: I have tryied that missing ")" but isnt that, now im getting error on last "}" from last function

Comment: also missing ";" from  $conn->query($sql) checking now if it works :D

Comment: manage to fix the script but i dont see what it should do, when i refresh it does nothing :-S

Comment: Pirjol. it’s only an example you must make a Database connection first. Greetings

Comment: i have edited my post with an EDIT where i have the connection to database, also created the database, any ideea whats wrong?

Comment: So nobody can help me? :|